# How to move the OPAM root?

Tags: build, ocaml, portable-applications, opam, utop

Is it possible to move the OPAM root? Or, to create a "portable" (in the sense of e.g. "firefox portable") version of an OPAM root?

That is, install a bunch of packages via `opam --root=/PATH/TO/A`, then move `/PATH/TO/A` to `/ANOTHER/PATH/TO/B`, and run everything from there.

A naive try led to a small error in "opam config env", where the old path slipped through. Also, some config files (findlib, global-config) had to be adjusted. After fixing that, some stuff worked, but "utop" fails with

`Fatal error: exception Not_found`

Is this a principle issue, or is a portable OPAM root just a matter of setting the right environment variables after the move?

Comment: Unfortunately as you've noticed, this is a bit package-dependent. You'll spend less time recompiling.

Comment: Each package uses their own paths, and many use absolute paths e.g. when running `./configure`. I don't think such packages can be easily made portable; even if you do a massive `sed` and manually replace their absolute paths with relative ones in every configuration file you find, it is possible some will stop working. For instance, they may have hardcoded absolute paths inside their binaries, so moving OPAM root would require recompiling them. Maybe some sort of `chroot` could work, but I don't know enough about it to suggest anything.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler itself is almost portable, a matter of setting environment variables `OCAMLLIB` and `CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the remaining problem is running bytecode executables which embed path to ocamlrun, see https://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5950 for details.

As for the packages - there is no universal guarantee, it all depends on what package does during the build. Majority of "normal" libraries that don't expect to find some data files at run time should work though. As comments above suggest, it is often faster to take snapshot of opam state (bundle) and rebuild in different path.